# asp.net forms - protecting forms(or folders) from unauthenticated users

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, sql-server-2005

i'm developing an asp.net app, using sql server 2005 and C#, i'm having issues with security. 
I've three users levels:

- level_3
- level_2
- level_1

Each user have an own form, the users are stored in a sql table like this:
user, password and level.
I can succesfully redirect each user to their respective form.
The issue i'm having is that I don't want to allow other users to be sniffing around the other forms. This is my code:

```
string level;
string connstring = @"Data Source=oyner-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=sat;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=login1;Password=?????????";
protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    string name = txtUser.Text;
    string password = txtPassword.Text;
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstring);
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmdd = new SqlCommand("SELECT level FROM users WHERE name = @name AND password = @pass", conn);
    cmdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name);
    cmdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", password);

    var firstColumn = cmdd.ExecuteScalar();
    if (firstColumn != null)
    {
        tipo = firstColumn.ToString();
        if (level == "Level_1")
        {                
            Response.Redirect("level_1/leve_1.aspx");                
        }
        if (level == "Level_2")
        { 
            Response.Redirect(""level_2/leve_2.aspx"");
        } 
        if (tipo == "Level_3")
        { 
            Response.Redirect(""level_3/leve_3.aspx"");
        } 


    }
    if (firstColumn == null)
    {
        lblMensaje.Text = "Access denied,";
    }
}
```

Any suggestion will be very useful

Comment: This is a decent first question, if you have tried *anything* as far as denying your users access to the other pages showing that would be great! I would store off the logged-in user in session data and check it on page load, but thats just me :)

Comment: "I'm inventing authentication scheme" and "I store passwords in clear text in DB" are two powerful vote magnets... beware. (Also almost compensated by using parametrized queries).

Comment: Nice answer, I would try to use a session variable to validate the user in the form_load to be allowed in their respective form, thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is roughly akin to User Roles in ASP.NET Authorization.

For instance, if Level 1 is Role1 (for example), Level 2 = Role2, etc. then you can specify in the web.config of the application that users of a particular group cannot view certain pages (e.g. your form pages). For example, to limit a particular page to Level1 users only, you would specify in your web.config something like:

```
<location path="Login\form1.aspx" >
<authorization>
  <allow roles="Level1"/>
  <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
</location>
```

Find out more about it here: [ASP.NET Authorization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/wce3kxhd%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)